# Why am I failing to use a font-family I've downloaded?

Tags: html, css

The .html I’m editing is ‘thrway2.html’. 
[image]

This is taking place in a `style` tag in my .html.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Those look suspiciously like curly quotes. You need straight quotes.

Comment: Those look like "smart quotes"... check the console.

Comment: Changing `"fonts/Ahem.ttf"` to `'fonts/Ahem.ttf'` solved it, thanks

Comment: I was copying the example under the section/header 'Web Fonts` in this article (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Web_fonts)

Comment: That page does not use smart quotes.

Comment: I'm with you now. My text-editor is Visual Studio Code. The only question I have to myself is how I used smart-quotes by accident.

Comment: Next time, please don't show pictures of code, copy and paste the code from your editor into the question as text, and format it as code (highlight the code and press Ctrl+K). Pictures of code are unreadable by search engines and people with visual impairments.

Comment: I understand but I probably wouldn't have found the answer to this question if I hadn't because I'm involving a local file on my computer, no?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I was using smart quotes around “fonts/Ahem.ttf”.

Comment: `".."` is fine. `“..”` is not.